# String - "break line" aka "paragraph line"

Tags: java, android, string

This should be simple, but I can't find how to solve it.

I need something that called "break line", "paragraph line" in typography, simply 4 or 5 spaces before text at the beginning of new paragraph.

I also need to store strings (string-array) in resources because it will be multy-lingual app.

all the text in resources looks like :

```
<item><![CDATA[TextTextText TextTextTextTextText.<br /><br />]]></item>
```

So, If I place 5 spaces before first letter of Text itself - Android will ignore them as it should. I thought - "ok, I'll make some char combination that I will later replace with spaces.Let's say "lNNl".

so I did :
(resources)

```
<item><![CDATA[lNNlTextTextText TextTextTextTextText.<br /><br />
lNNl TExttext<br />]]></item>
```

(code)

```
for (int i=0;i<tv_id.length;i++){ 
 tv[i]=(TextView)  view.findViewById(tv_id[i]);
String tabbedString=conversations[i].replaceAll("lNNl", "    ");//lNNl is what I want to replace
          Spanned sp=Html.fromHtml(tabbedString);
         tv[i].setText(sp);
```

Aaaaaand.. Spaces at the beginning of the line are ignored again.

I understand that it should be solved simply..somehow .. but can't find a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
String tabbedString=conversations[i].replaceAll("lNNl", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
```

Comment: Strangely enough, I need two of them for 1 space and 8 for 4 spaces) and I can do it form resources as well. But.. it doesn't look pretty at all. anyway, thanks, I got limit of 5 minutes to accept answer